# Trying to fill up a Matrix using python lists

Tags: python, list, matrix

So , i just got a problem trying to make **a Matrix** and fill up it with numbers , here is the code

```
from math import*

def Proc_saisie():
    X = -1
    while X < 10 or X > 40 :
        X = int(input("Donner un entier entre 10 et 40 : "))
    return X


def Proc_Remplir(T,X):
    T= []
    for i in range(X):
        for j in range(X):
            d = int(input("T["+str(i)+","+str(j)+"]="))
            T[j].append(d)
        T[i].append(T[j])
    return T




A = Proc_saisie()

TAB = []

TAB = Proc_Remplir(TAB,A)

print(TAB)
```

I always get the error of **List index out of range** even i tried many solutions and tips i follow on google .

I wish you help me and **Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise the 2d array with the empty sub-arrays i.e.

```py
T = []
for _ in range(X):
    T.append([])
# T = [[], [], []... X times]
```

or

```py
T = [[] for _ in range(X)]
```

then you can add to each.

(Full code)

```py
from math import *

def Proc_saisie():
    X = -1
    while X < 10 or X > 40 :
        X = int(input("Donner un entier entre 10 et 40 : "))
    return X


def Proc_Remplir(T,X):
    # Populate list with empty rows so that they can be added to
    T = [[] for _ in range(X)]
    print(T) # Debugger to demonstrate how empty lists are created within the master list
    for i in range(X):
        for j in range(X):
            d = int(input("T["+str(i)+","+str(j)+"]="))
            T[i].append(d)
        # T[i].append(T[j]) # This line is unnecessary
    return T




A = Proc_saisie()

TAB = []

TAB = Proc_Remplir(TAB,A)

print(TAB)
```

Comment: And then `T[i].append(T[j])` can be removed as well.

Comment: Still not understand , am trying to put multi lists in a list . the way you showed me is just to fill 1 list as i know ..

Comment: @koukou updated with full code. In order to add to a certain row in a matrix, the row must first exist as an empty row, siignified by a list within a list.

Comment: @koukou This might help your understanding? [2D arrays tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_2darray.htm)

Comment: @MatthewMiles Big thanks Mr .. your code works perfectly and run totaly okau .. and also gave me another vision of making solution for my future Code .. thanks again :D

Comment: @koukou no problem! glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you appending at `T[j]` when at this point T is just a empty list.

```
def Proc_saisie():
    X = -1
    while X < 3 or X > 40 :
        X = int(input("Donner un entier entre 10 et 40 : "))
    return X


def Proc_Remplir(X):
    T= []   # Creates list

    for i in range(X):
        tmp = []    # Creates new sublist
        for j in range(X):
            d = int(input("T["+str(i)+","+str(j)+"]="))
            tmp.append(d)   # Append to sublist
        T.append(tmp)   # Append sublist to list.

    # T will now contain a list of lists.
    return T

A = Proc_saisie()

TAB = Proc_Remplir(A) # dont need to pass TAB as you create new array in function

print(TAB)

for l in TAB:
    print(l)

#[OUT]:
#Donner un entier entre 10 et 40 : 3
#T[0,0]=1
#T[0,1]=2
#T[0,2]=3
#T[1,0]=4
#T[1,1]=5
#T[1,2]=6
#T[2,0]=7
#T[2,1]=8
#T[2,2]=9

#[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

#[1, 2, 3]
#[4, 5, 6]
#[7, 8, 9]
```

Your function could also be written as a one-liner using list comprehensions:

```
T = [[int(input("T["+str(i)+","+str(j)+"]=")) for j in range(X)] for i in range(X)]
```

Yields the same results.

Comment: Your method worked for me too ... big thanks for your effort for helping me to find the answer <3